# Kalman Filter: Effect on covariance from frauded errorneous sensor

Tags: kalman-filters

I have recently started to learn about Kalman filters and I am right now simulating a very simple model in Simulink giving a noisy sinewave (position) and its derivative (speed). I have implemented/parameterized two redundant filters:

1. The Kalman Filter Block included in the control system toolbox (Simulink)
2. A matlab function using mainly the code given on this site: https://www.cbcity.de/das-kalman-filter-einfach-erklaert-teil-2

As both ways give plausible and equal results, I assume no major bug in my implementation.

I assume both states to be measureable. However, if I falsify one of the measured states to a completely stupid value, the value of the covariance and Kalman gain stays constant (after it converged to a fix value from its initial state). From my understanding, the values should change as less confidence can be put into the falsified state.

Is this expectation correct?

Thanks for your help.

Phil

Comment: How did you "falsify" the state value?  If you just inserted an erroneous value into the state, how would the filter know that the state had changed -- from it's view -- spontaneously?  Can you show where in the Kalman filter equations you would anticipate this false state value to be detected and the resulting detection applied to the covariance matrix?

Comment: To falsify the value, I simply added a inconsistent value to one of the input states. Fro my understanding of Kalman filtering, as this falsification causing a huge aberration of the predicted (modelled) value, Kalmangain and thus the Covariance (as a metric for the trustfulness of the estimated output state) should drop, indicating something inconsistent happened on the input. Is this view correct? Thanks for commenting.

Comment: Nope.  **Look at the filter equations**.  The evolution of the covariance matrix is *completely* determined by the filter structure; it isn't affected at all by the value of the states or the inputs.

Comment: Alright. This supports what I've already analysed. Before working with Kalman filters, my understanding was that it adapts quite well to changes in input behaviour, also a collegue of mine gave me this impression. Now I know better, you actualy have to characterize your system + noise quite well before you can expect reasonable results. Thanks for helping me understand!

Comment: The reason that you can't falsify a state like that is because a straight Kalman filter starts with the assumption that all of the distributions are Gaussian and known.  An atypically large value on a variable is so rare in a Gaussian distributed system that the Kalman filter doesn't take it into account.  If you were to start by assuming a different distribution (or a distribution that is Gaussian but unknown) then the filter structure would be, first, different, and second, much more complicated.